# Object detections/object recogntion?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection, object-recognition

I have a slight confusion defferentiating between object recognition and object detection. Some people say object detection is a sub-topic of object recognition? Can someone clarify the the difference between these two topics?

To  the best of my knowledge.

Object Recognition is responding to the question "What is the object in the image"
Whereas,
Object detection is answering the question "Where is that object"?

Hope someone can illustrate the difference by also generously providing an example to each

Comment: is nt allowed to asked theoretical question? First time to know that it just about technical and programmming, well, this topics can be explained in a programming form if you know what I mean

Comment: I'm really suggesting a [similar site](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/) where you may get a better response - there are many questions like yours here, sometimes they get good response, sometimes not. This site is really about programming questions, with very well defined problems and solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not a clear answer to this in the literature and many authors give these two terms different meanings or use them interchangeably, depending on the application. If I remember correctly, [Szeliski in "Computer vision: Algorithms and applications"](http://szeliski.org/Book/) defines them in a way similar to this:

- Object detection: to notice there is an object in an image and to know where it is in the image. So, you can outline the object but you may not know what object it is.
- Object (or instance) recognition: to actually say what object you have detected, and maybe providing additionally information, such as where the object is located in the 3D space.

In some applications, such as recognizing and object to grasp it with a robotic arm, the recognition is just a verification step done after a detection, so that if you are not able to recognize the object, you cannot verify the detection and discard it (because it may be a false positive). For this reason "detection" and "recognition" are used as the same task sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

Object recognition - which object is in the given image (which contains an object alone).

Object detection - which object is in the given image (which depicts a scene containing more than one object and is generally taken without constraints of background or view point) and where is it located.

Answer (score 1):

If we take face as subset of object => face detection is to detect a face in an image, and then face recognition is to recognize the face as Angelina Jolie for example.